# How to find path to XLA file in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7

Tags: vba, excel, xla

When I open Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7, I see the project window. I.e. file1.xla, file2.xlam, etc. If I have multiple files names file1.xla, how do I know which one I'm looking at? I can't find the path to the file in the IDE.

I have some Excel plugins installed, which might be why some files continuously show up in the list.

Comment: In the Immediate Window, you can type: `?Workbooks("File1.xla").path` for example

Comment: Do you want to submit as answer @Rory? It looks like that works

Comment: That method won't work well if there are multiple files with the same name as you stated in the question.

Comment: I'm new to VBA but I didn't think you can open more than one file with the same name

Comment: You can if one is an add-in.  And if you think it's impossible why did you state it in your question?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't have two add-ins with the same file name (including extension) open.

Comment: I didn't say that I had multiple files open at the same time @Mr.Mascaro. I have multiple files with the same name on my local file system

Comment: @Hoppe, OK.  Now I understand.  You probably want to make that more clear in your question.  There are many ways to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Immediate Window, you can type:

```
?Workbooks("File1.xla").path
```

for example.

Comment: `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the path of the currently active `VBProject` by using:
`Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.FileName`

You can also get all paths by looping through the `Application.VBE.VBProjects` collection.

Comment: I can use some hand holding as I'm new to VBA... I get "invalid use of property" when I run this from the immediate window

Comment: Both result in "Application-defined or object defined error". It seems like "Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted" when I try ?Application.VBE

Comment: Ok.  You'll need to go into the Trust Center and select: "Trust access to the VBA project object model."  Now that you're a developer this is a very good thing to enable.